# Unwanted read-only network interface (ifupdown)

Tags: networking, mate-desktop

I have an Android TV box running [Armbian](https://www.armbian.com/) 5.41 (Ubuntu 16.04.5). Since I changed from kodi-standalone to MATE, I've found a network issue.

The box is connected via Ethernet, and MATE shows two interfaces: eth0 and ifupdown(eth0). I want to use eth0, because i can not set an static IP on ifupdown, because it's ready-only. Every time I restart MATE, it automatically connects to ifupdown, resulting in not having any network.

I need the static IP, because I've got [Pi-Hole](https://pi-hole.net/) running on it as well, with an enabled DHCP server. The static IP of eth0 has been set in network manager. How can i remove this interface or at least setting the normal eth0 as default?

/etc/network/interfaces

```
# Wired adapter #1
allow-hotplug eth0
no-auto-down eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
#address 192.168.0.17
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.0.1
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
#       hwaddress ether # if you want to set MAC manually
#       pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth0 mtu 3838 # setting MTU for DHCP, static just: mtu 3838


# Wireless adapter #1
# Armbian ships with network-manager installed by default. To save you time
# and hassles consider using 'sudo nmtui' instead of configuring Wi-Fi settings
# manually. The below lines are only meant as an example how configuration could
# be done in an anachronistic way:
#
#allow-hotplug wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#address 192.168.0.100
#netmask 255.255.255.0
#gateway 192.168.0.1
#dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
#   wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
# Disable power saving on compatible chipsets (prevents SSH/connection dropouts over WiFi)
#wireless-mode Managed
#wireless-power off

# Local loopback
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: ifupdown supports static IPs, for what it's worth. see for example https://askubuntu.com/questions/637948/set-static-ip-problem/637970

Answer (score 0):

From `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# Armbian ships with network-manager installed by default. To save you time
# and hassles consider using 'sudo nmtui' instead of configuring Wi-Fi settings
# manually.
```

Edit the `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` then change the following:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

to

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

The Network-Manager will not manage the network interfaces configured under `/etc/network/interfaces` then run:

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

Use the command `sudo nmtui` to configure a static IP.